# Consulta SQL con AVG MAX y 3 tablas

Tags: sql

Tengo las siguientes 3 tablas:

> Turista (**idTur**, nombre, apellido1, apellido2)
>
> Museo (**codiMus**, nomMus, ciudad)
>
> Visita (**tur, codiMus, fecha,**
> valoracion) on {tur} referencia a Turista(idTur) i {codiMus}
> referencia a Museo (codiMus)

Estoy intentando realizar la siguiente consulta:
Obtener la ciudad que tiene el promedio de valoraciones mayor de sus museos.

Llego a obtener la media de las valoraciones por ciudad, pero no consigo obtener el max:

```
Select m2.ciudad, avg(v2.valoracion) 
From Visita v2, Museo m2 
Where v2.codiMus = m2.codiMus 
Group by m2.ciudad
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Que BBDD usas?

Comment: MySql a través de phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba hacerlo de esta manera a ver si te sirve:

```
SELECT m2.ciudad, avg(v2.valoracion) 
FROM Visita v2, Museo m2 
WHERE v2.codiMus = m2.codiMus 
GROUP BY m2.ciudad
ORDER BY avg(v2.valoracion) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Ordenamos por el campo promedio `avg(v2.valoracion)` en orden descendente y limitamos a 1 las filas para que así nos muestre la ciudad que tiene el museo con mayor promedio.

Es una manera de hacerlo, pero seguro que no la mas optima.

Comment: Finalmente lo había hecho justo así. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Sobre las mismas tablas también me piden obtener el nombre y apellidos de los turistas que han visitado todos y cada uno de los museos. He llegado a la siguiente query pero no sé si existe una forma más eficiente de hacerlo: SELECT t.nom, t.cog1, t.cog2 FROM Turista t WHERE t.idTur IN 
 (SELECT v2.tur
 FROM Visita v2
 GROUP BY v2.tur
 HAVING count(DISTINCT v2.codi) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Museu))         Gracias de nuevo!!!